# How can I check whether a row name exists in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to address the rows of a data frame by a string name, and the table will be built sequentially. I want to do something like

```
> mytab <- data.frame(city=c("tokyo","delhi","lima"),price=c(9,8,7),row.names=1)
> mytab
      price
tokyo     9
delhi     8
lima      7 
> # I can add a new row
> mytab["london",] = 8.5
```

I now need to check whether a row name already exists.

```
> mytab["ny",]
[1] NA
```

Is there anything better that I can do other than

`> if (is.na(mytab["ny",])) { mytab["ny",]=9;}`

since a `NA` may possibly arise otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

```
if (!('ny' %in% row.names(mytab))) {mytab['ny',]=9}
```

might do the trick.

Comment: That should do it, but it seems like this will have `O(n)` time complexity due to a linear search, and may be `O(n)` space complexity due to forming a `row.names(mytab)`. Is this true? And is row name search always a linear search anyway?

Comment: @highBandWidth - sungam has a rather fast answer, but each lookup is indeed O(n). Your comment makes me wonder: do you want to test many rownames, and if so, could you do it in one go?

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of ways to do this. One of the easiest is to use the any() function like this:

```
# Returns true if any of the row names is 'lima', false otherwise.
any(row.names(mytab) == 'lima')
```

Since this returns a boolean, you can branch conditionals from it as you please.

Comment: Thanks! I think you mean `any(row.names(mytab) == 'lima')` instead. I guess its the same approach as @sungam's. Do you know if the regular row name lookup is better than a linear search?

Comment: Should it be `any(row.names(mytab) == 'lima')` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach if you want to check several cities in one go. That could help speed things up...

```
mytab <- data.frame(city=c("tokyo","delhi","lima"),price=c(9,8,7),row.names=1)

# Check several cities in one go:
newcities <- c('foo', 'delhi', 'bar')

# Returns the missing cities:
setdiff(newcities, row.names(mytab))
#[1] "foo" "bar"

# Returns the existing cities:
intersect(newcities, row.names(mytab))
#[1] "delhi"
```